# Type safe function parameters and return type based on a defined interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a fully type-safe function for an internal messaging system.
My goal is to have a fuction that will accpet only specific parameters for a given action (string) and will return correct return type - all defined in a single `interface` or union of `type`s.

I've tried 3 different variations and it almost works, but not completely.

```js
interface Actions {
  a: {                      // name of the action ('a')
    params: { x: number },  // parameters for the function
    result: number,         // return type for the function
  },
  b: {                      // same with the action 'b'
    params: { y: number },
    result: string,
  },
}

function action<U extends keyof Actions, T extends Actions[U]>(action: U, params: T['params']): T['result'] {   // error: Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.
  switch (action) {
    case 'a': return params.x;          // error: Property 'x' does not exist on type '{ x: number; } | { y: number; }'.
    case 'b': return String(params.y);  // error: Property 'y' does not exist on type '{ x: number; } | { y: number; }'.
  }
}
// calling the action works great though with proper parameter type narrowing and correct return type
const result: number = action('a', {x: 42});
```

All 3 of my experiments are here in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIILMA9iAzsgbwFgAoZZOALkPNrvofIHonkQ4BbFLGZMACxSJMOZAAoA5HAkBKUnQAOcKJ1zUCyAB7UQAVw4AjaMgC%20AGmaslKrpCj4YWKH0HIYukBmwh5tKBFxdABswHX0jKAtGZBZkfzBdKBA%20AE8FFEdnAQyPLxxfc18DdWjS%20ljcThQAd2ABFyE85IkDCV9ya1USlLDDY0KyPwDg0ORcMChQAHMzAtmSE1JSd08RZOFvAB4AVWQITUgQABN8AGsIFJ40JtwLABU9g4hj-HQ13ABtbYBdAD4xDY4ajbCydDhqZB3D4SMG4CTfGTUKESfyBELwmiWPZQKBOagAMVya2QQUQp3wzyO0ziEASSTGYDgkC44AoxxpdOSYDSKCOWACbCwYGQoAQQV0RxQEg8kpgoAgRwkADpfLhamAEPxxICQDJCO1kAg4LgpdJqPFEslYUrNABuMqxaC4qDUAAKuPSUG5yAkmgkyD5ApAQsewHGyFE3PSPo02jY4Wg9pMyAAPjQevG%20lAk8qDUaTT7WubaZbkABlCbTMTWlIye0xVhOvHId1YT3eiQpf2B-DB4X7MPCyM8mNaXoRJOp9PjxOmXODRYLUixI1BILUnXIapOcnIKb%20JmUUgIHDh1EjGfOAC8FCakmkFgIcYALAAmEx1pYkWJUmAwaDPMKcAKAoKiahYBi6MKlRcMgoFYAYQQQBwR4kKQUYoKgCjAMgN7EIMGHUFIEjzB0yhdDQcZ6FmpikTSaLCpe8zJmm%20HkIRhYkb4sLdJetG%20OeITUOMkwgDMpCLssRLeBQ2GbA8%20yHCcaDYf8OpItCGHwqC5HghpMK6XCCL6YJYAYhoDbYs6BLSaIpIILulLUha9LjEyyGAWyRwcqWGEBvyvYhqK4qSj6MoQHKIAKvO5BqnUmrak0epsbQ%20amhIxacnBhk2vW0SOjizatu2KQ%20n6-lBiGA7hsO0YSLGl6TqxyAZtRE5ziqgzkGlnGZaWFaiVM1Y5bW9YFdZLYetAHZdhVgX9pog4RlyI71WOmbtSx04bbOJgxaYElfrEADMUDecB8GIFqAC0yAAEQYXdIqBdU2VehGvDZG9qgRgYABWEAYGMWDfeCFD%20Gwyi4tUCr%20dUyQnjigNgEEKQQVBPn0n5YYMsAa4UMgHjeF%20fllronpYTheHcYZJQccRFhUQmzgDOQpnIExElTilPE0PTrQWK1zP8YMpnCZWYnMV%20KxNGM5PQJT8mPEp%20BkxTqnDTYELIrC8KIpC0KmeZqrqglmuqEqGHJXmxrpX19LWpoyAANQ%20tUcB1BY1T8EyAD8Eh5bEAg47g-BYME3nwHjyC3S5K3RhwujhkYBNtdAACENsFi0GWY8kA1VjWdbIAUh0kEAA).
**But all of them have errors.** The one above is the best looking but there are 3 errors which I can't fix.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: When TS4.6 lands you'll be able to do [this](https://tsplay.dev/WG5dKN) to achieve this sort of type safety with these "correlated" inputs, as per [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).   Until then you pretty much need type assertions to quiet the errors.  Would you like me to write up an answer explaining this?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks! Those type assertions looks like an interesting workaround, but I have way to many actions so this would be too many lines to manage. But you are saying I can already do this in beta 4.6? That would be great, I don't mind using beta for those few months till it's released.

Comment: Just to be clear: type assertions look like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WYvlrw) and basically just suppress errors by telling the compiler that a value is of a particular type that it can't verify, and so is only effortlessly type safe from the caller's side; the implementer needs to take care to make things safe.  On the other hand,  the refactoring where you look up a function by key and call it on a correlated input doesn't need type assertions, and it can indeed be used now with beta 4.6.  So which if any of this would you like to see as an answer?

Comment: @jcalz yeah, I'm sorry I got confused. Definitely not the type assertion, that's super inconvenient to write each time I use a parameter. The object with functions sounds much better. Also, now that I'm thinking about it, I could also write multiple function definition (function overloading), right? But it's not exactly nice looking either :(. What would you do? I feel like this is such a common problem yet I can't find any good solution.

Comment: The underlying issue is either https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581 (which is essentially fixed by the solution I gave above, as of TS4.6) or https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808 which is still not addressed.  It's common but tends to affect library implementers and not library users (e.g., callers of `action()` don't have the problem) so it's not the highest of priorities and it's non-trivial to fix.  If TS4.6 were already released in an wide use I'd probably refactor, but until then I'd do the equivalent of type assertions (e.g., lots of `any`)

Comment: Thank you @jcalz, I guess I can wait for 4.6 and until then just ignore those errors. If you re-write the info from the comment to the answer I will give it flag. Thank you for linking those github issues! I'm happy to see it's in progress and that I can look forward to the new release!

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get a chance (probably not before I go to sleep).

Comment: @jcalz Let it be, I really don't want to take any more of your time. I'm sure you are a busy man and for now I can manage by forcing a type in each case block with: `const data = params as Actions['a']['params'];`. Thank you for all the help!